# Lambda`s internal this in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, this

If lambda function ic C++ is implemented by functor, why this is not possible?

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public: 
    int a;  
    void f1(){ [](){std::cout << this << std::endl ;}();};
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.f1();
}
```

I get error `9:34: error: 'this' was not captured for this lambda function`. If I understand it right, if lambda is implemented as a functor class, why it is not possible to get it`s internal **this**?

EDIT: **this** of functor class, not **this** of instance of class A.

Comment: You need to capture it in like `[this] () {}` or by value or reference

Comment: @A.A by capturing it like you said I capture A`s this.

Comment: It just isn't possible. What's the point?

Comment: yes. you do not need lambda's this. You have all the variables in the capture list anyway

Comment: It's not really true that "lambda's are implemented via functors". Lambdas are a first class feature... they're implemented by the compiler itself. It's just that in practical terms, lambdas end up being essentially equivalent to an anonymous unique struct declared in a certain way. Note the weasel word essentially; they are not 100% the same and this is one such example. Probably it wasn't done because a) there's no use case, and b) this allows this to refer to the enclosing class' this when you declare a lambda in a member function.

Comment: What would you do with a `this` pointer for a lambda?

Comment: One thing you could do with it is recursion.

Comment: I dont need it, I`m just interested how does it works.

Comment: "why this is not possible?" - The short, pithy answer is "because the standard says so". The longer reasoning would be that it would be ambiguous with lambdas which captured `this` or `&`.

Comment: Lambdas can also get inlined by the compiler. Then there is no such thing like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

> For the purpose of name lookup, determining the type and value of the
>   this pointer and for accessing non-static class members, the body of
>   the closure type's function call operator is considered in the context
>   of the lambda-expression.

```
struct X {
    int x, y;
    int operator()(int);
    void f()
    {
        // the context of the following lambda is the member function X::f
        [=]()->int
        {
            return operator()(this->x + y); // X::operator()(this->x + (*this).y)
                                            // this has type X*
        };
    }
};
```

So, it is impossible to reference `this` as you wish.